# Crop images in Javascript html

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, jquery-mobile, crop

I am developing a webpage in which I have to show some photos from Facebook. I use jQuery mobile.

Now I can show a list dynamically with all photos with their titles and so. But the images are displayed in thumbs version and are not all equals. All photos in landscape mode are okay, but photos in vertical mode are narrower than the others and the list is not oay.

I want to crop all the images to see them smaller and all equals. For example, 20x20 or so.

I have found many answer about this. I tried some of them but no ones works. I tried one with cats in their example, I have seen it in many answer but I couldn't make it to work. I think it is because all examples are for static images and not dynamically generated list like mine.

This is my code for generating the list and put the photos with title and description.

```
$("#photosNJ").after('<div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" id=Gallery'+ i +
    ' class="gallery-page"' + ' data-url="Gallery' + i + '"> ' +
    ' <div data-role="header"><h1>Gallery</h1></div> ' + ' <div data-role="content"> ' +
    ' <ul class="gallery"></ul> ' + ' </div> ' +
    ' </div> ');

for (var n=0; n < albumPhotos[i].length; n++) {
    $('#Gallery' + i + ' .gallery').append('<li><a href="' + albumPhotos[i][n] 
        + '"  rel="external"><img src="' +  albumThumbnails[i][n] + '"' + '/> </a> </li>');
}
```

I pass the album I want to show and a number which is the number of the album for controlling how many of them I have set.

I don't know how to call inside my code an already done script for cropping the photos. I don't need to select a good part of the image, just to crop it from the left upper(or down) corner to the 20x20 (or whatever) point. If I can get the images from Facebook in other sizes or already crop, it is also a good solution.

As first comment said, I added the CSS to my CSS file and set the code like this:

```
for(var n=0; n < albumPhotos[i].length; n++) {
                //console.log("cropping");
                $('#Gallery' + i + ' .gallery').append('<li><a href="' + albumPhotos[i][n] 
                + '"  rel="external"><img class="crop" src="' +  albumThumbnails[i][n] + '"' + '/> </a> </li>');
           }
```

But the images are displayed in the same way. I tried that solution in my main page, setting it hard coded and it works. The image is cropped. But when I try to generate the list dynamically, it doesn't. Anyone knows how to solve it?

Comment: do like this, apply styles to images http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/HPs55/

Comment: I tried your example and it works fine, that is what I want to get. I modified like this: http://jsfiddle.net/HPs55/2/ But when I add the css to my css file and set class="crop" inside img tag, it doesn't work. Maybe it is because I am redering the table dinamically? I don't know...
I tried to add an image and it is cropped, so the problem is while rendering the table in javscript.

Comment: might the css attribute background-size: cover; help?

Comment: The page renders normally and gets all classes added? when checking the page source, can you see everything added?

Comment: I had some problems. Now it works. I was setting the class parameter in wrong place. Now it is working like a charm, thanks all for your help